# PHP micro-optimization

Tags: php, micro-optimization

How can I spot useless micro-optimization techniques?

What should be avoided?

Comment: Micro-optimizations are useless when they are an eye-drain. It very occasionally makes sense to honor them in loops however, if and only if huge piles of data are processed there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any optimization done without being measured and profiled first is useless.

PHP code profilers:

- [xDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/)
- [PHP_Debug](http://phpdebug.sourceforge.net/www/index.html)
- [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) (Sometimes it is easy to spot bottlenecks in the code using a simple `echo time()`)

Always measure before optimizing!

Answer (score 4):

Write code that works and is readable. If you find it sluggish, you can always do some [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

I'm making myself unpopular and say `isset`.

To check for undefined variables `isset()` is often used throughout application logic. Many people however only use it with the intent to suppress notices. It's use seldomly contributes to further procession logic. And more specifically it is used over `@`, the error suppression operator. And that's because there is the @slowness myth.

The thing is, it's not a myth. Using `@` for accessing undefined variables drains processing speed. In my very unscientific test, it did so by **535%**. I'm making it bold to underline the uselessness of that number. Because in real world applications you won't have 10 million occourences to measure it. (Like the 13-14% tokenizer speedup of 'single' quotes has no impact on the overall script runtime.) Otherwise this performance disadvantage wouldn't really show. And that's why I conclude that eschewing `@` for overflowing usage of `isset` is also a micro-optimization.

Comment: Well, @ also can hide other logic errors besides unset variables. If you code your application properly, you should rarely have a case when a variable is unset when it should be.

Comment: @ is bad for plenty of reasons other than simply being slow, it makes debugging a nightmare.

Comment: @GordonM: Actually neither. It's not `@` itself which causes a noticeable speed drop, it's the notice generation. And btw, having more notices does not make debugging a nightmare. Having them suppressed does. (@-suppressed debug messages can be brought back, isset-suppressed onces never)

Comment: (noticeable = as in actually using a profiler, not making assumptions about it)

Comment: `function myFunction()(<some code with @ in it>}; $var = myFunction();`  =>  good luck debugging it when the code is deep inside thousand of lines.  `isset` is better as you KNOW ahead of time that the variable should be set to keep going (I am not talking about `!isset($var) && $var = 'someval';` but about more complex code)